# Can the Avangate ESD API upload the latest version of my software distribution?

Tags: build, automation, avangate

I would like my build machine (or one that has access to the build machine's artifacts) to receive an event from me that will cause it to upload the indicated artifact (new release) to my Avangate account's respective product so that the very next order's download link delivers the new release.

Can it be done with the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avangate's ESD API does not provide that feature. It's entirely a manual process unless you like writing your own web client that can adapt to Avangate's engineering whims.